# Updating Records in FileNet using CSV

Tags: filenet-p8

I have a csv file with unknown number of rows:

```
id,name,title,salary,time
123,abc,manager,10000,12:30
456,xyz,s manager,15000,13:45
789,tuv,junior,5000,09:15
123,abc,manager,10000,14:15
123,abc,manager,10000,15:35
```

Notice that above, I have a duplicate 3 records with `id=123` and `salary=10000`.

In FileNet I have below records:

```
id,name,title,salary,status,sequence,time
123,abc,manager,10000,success,1,0
123,abc,manager,10000,failure,2,0
123,abc,manager,10000,failure,3,0
789,tuv,junior,5000,failure,1,0
```

Notice that above I have 3 duplicates, one with `success` and 2 with `failure` statuses.

My requirement is that I have to sequentially compare one by one row from my csv file with FileNet records, order by sequence and if any rows with the same id and salary match the records in FileNet (lookup is done using `id` and `salary` fields), I need to update the time and status to `success`.

E.g. one row `(123,abc,manager,10000,12:30)` in csv file above with one record `(123,abc,manager,10000,failure,2,0)` in FileNet.

The end result in FileNet should be:

```
id,name,title,salary,status,time
123,abc,manager,10000,success,1,0
123,abc,manager,10000,success,2,12:30
123,abc,manager,10000,success,3,14:15
789,tuv,junior,5000,success,1,09:15
```

note:
insertion of the first row
`(123,abc,manager,10000,12:30)` should update the FileNet record
`(123,abc,manager,10000,failure,2,0)`.
The fourth row
`(123,abc,manager,10000,14:15)` should update the FileNet record `(123,abc,manager,10000,failure,3,0)`.
The third row
`(789,tuv,junior,5000,09:15)` should update the FileNet record `(789,tuv,junior,5000,failure,1,0)`.

Also note there is a another last row(123,abc,manager,10000,15:35) in csv file which will not update any record in FileNet as the records are updated sequentially in FileNet.

I hope the requirement is clear. Please help as I'm a FileNet newbie.

Comment: So what did you already try? This is not a place to look for complete software solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your algorithm in Java, reading the CSV and using the [P8 Content Engine Java API](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/p8docs/v5r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc%2Fdev_ce_intro.htm) to do the comparisons and updates to FileNet.

If you get stuck using the FileNet Java API, [this](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247743.pdf) may help.